# How to decode a string from Instagram backup in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, instagram, decoding

This is a part of my Instagram account backup

```
[
  {
    "media": [
      {
        "title": "\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To parse this I use `Codable`

```
struct BlogPost: Codable {
    let media: [Media]
}

struct Media: Codable {
    let title: String
}
```

But this code prints **ÐÐ¾ÑÐ¾Ð³Ð¾Ð¹ Ð´ÑÑÐ³**

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let path = bundle.path(forResource: "posts_1", ofType: "json")
let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: path!)
let data = content!.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([BlogPost].self, from: data)
print(result![0].media[0].title)
```

And it should print **Дорогой друг**. How to decode this string on iOS? I am also using [mothereff.in](https://mothereff.in/utf-8#%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3) to decode backup data.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - some code that I can copy and paste into a playground and see the output you got.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Why would someone code the backend to encode a string this way? That's about the least efficient way it could be done. Are you sure you are getting the data from the backend correctly? Perhaps you should include relevant code showing how you access the data.

Comment: @HangarRash This is my IG account backup data.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually the value in your string? I highly suspect that this is some raw binary, that you tried to print as a string, which was escaped using `\u` notation to make it appear string-like, when it was never a string to begin with.

Comment: What you have given as string looks like a string literal for Java, JavaScript, C# and possibly other languages. Swift uses different syntax, so the given string literal does not compile in Swift. It also looks like, this string has been created by taking octets from a byte array and converting them individually into an unicode representation and concatenating them. This makes no sense at all. So, if you actually got this from the server, the is just plain wrong. You may try to reverse the process, though and get a valid string back. However, you should contact your backend team.

Comment: If you treat those hex numbers as Unicode code points, the string you get back is correct. For example, Unicode code point `00d0` really is Ð. whereas Д is `0414` or `D0 94` in UTF-8 (Which tells me exactly what has gone wrong here).

Comment: Now that you've shown more code, it would be even more helpful to show how you encode the data when creating your backup. I just did a quick test using your structures and a value of "Дорогой друг" for the title and the resulting JSON is not encoded as you show at all.

Comment: @HangarRash I am using https://mothereff.in/utf-8#Дорогой%20друг to decode.

Comment: No, I'm asking you to show your Swift code that originally encodes a `BlogPost` into the JSON that you save to the backup file. I have no idea what that link is for or why you would use it.

Comment: @HangarRash instagram.com does this. You can create a backup of your profile in the settings. Then they will send this JSON to your email.

Comment: @RomanPodymov I'm not on Instagram so I can't test that. Are you saying that the JSON they provide you has the title values encoded just as you show in your question? In other words, the JSON that they provide actually has the value "Дорогой друг" encoded as "\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b3" ?

Comment: @HangarRash Correct. Also tested it with mothereff.in/utf-8#Дорогой%20друг, so I can fix the issue with JS, but searching for something similar in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by summarizing some details. Instagram is encoding the string `"Дорогой друг"` as `"\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b3"`

Let's look at what this means. The `Д` is the Unicode character U+0414. It has a UTF-8 encoding of `D0 94`. Note that the encoded title in the JSON begins with `\u00d0\u0094`. Then the `о` is the Unicode character U+043E with a UTF-8 encoding of `D0 BE`. And sure enough, the encoded title in the JSON has `\u00d0\u00be` as the next set of values. So it seems that Instagram is encoding the string as UTF-8 while using the `\uxxxx` escape characters. At least for the Cyrillic characters. The space is encoded as a regular space character.

The problem is that `JSONDecoder` expects that if a string contains escaped characters in the form `\uxxxx`, it assumes the code is the Unicode value, not part of the UTF-8 encoding. When it parses the title, it first sees `\u00d0`. That's the Unicode character `Ð`. Then it sees `\u0094`. That's the Unicode character "CANCEL CHARACTER", a non-printable character. This continues and you end up with `"ÐÐ¾ÑÐ¾Ð³Ð¾Ð¹ Ð´ÑÑÐ³"`.

`JSONDecoder` has no built-in functionality to tell it how to handle Instagram's non-standard encoding of strings. So this means the only solution is to write a custom decoder.

Here is a working solution. Update your `Media` struct as follows:

```swift
struct Media: Codable {
    let title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let str = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        let data = Data(str.reduce([], { partialResult, char in
            char.unicodeScalars.reduce(into: partialResult) { partialResult, scalar in
                partialResult.append(UInt8(scalar.value))
            }
        }))
        let res = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        self.title = res ?? "" // some fallback as desired
    }
}
```

This is fine if there's only the one value to handle. If you need to deal with this for more than one property, move the logic to a `String` extension:

```swift
extension String {
    var fromInstagramEncoding: String? {
        let data = Data(self.reduce([], { partialResult, char in
            char.unicodeScalars.reduce(into: partialResult) { partialResult, scalar in
                partialResult.append(UInt8(scalar.value))
            }
        }))

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Then the updated `Media` code becomes:

```swift
struct Media: Codable {
    let title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let str = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.title = str.fromInstagramEncoding ?? "" // some fallback as desired
    }
}
```

---

Here's a complete example that can be run in a Playground:

```swift
struct BlogPost: Codable {
    let media: [Media]
}

struct Media: Codable {
    let title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let str = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.title = str.fromInstagramEncoding ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var fromInstagramEncoding: String? {
        let data = Data(self.reduce([], { partialResult, char in
            char.unicodeScalars.reduce(into: partialResult) { partialResult, scalar in
                partialResult.append(UInt8(scalar.value))
            }
        }))

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}

let instagramJSON = """
[
  {
    "media": [
      {
        "title" : "\\u00d0\\u0094\\u00d0\\u00be\\u00d1\\u0080\\u00d0\\u00be\\u00d0\\u00b3\\u00d0\\u00be\\u00d0\\u00b9 \\u00d0\\u00b4\\u00d1\\u0080\\u00d1\\u0083\\u00d0\\u00b3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
"""

let badData = instagramJSON.data(using: .utf8)!
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([BlogPost].self, from: badData)
print(result[0].media[0].title)
```

Output:

> Дорогой друг

---

Note that this solution works with the provided example. It's possible that Instagram encodes some characters in such a way that this solution could fail in some cases. Without more data I can't know for sure. Post a comment with relevant details if you come across an example that this code doesn't handle correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Before @HangarRash [added the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78023001/2229783), I was using [utf8.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js). I copied **utf8.js** to my project, then I called `utf8.decode` from Swift:

```
import JavaScriptCore

extension String {
    var asIGTitle: String? {
        guard let context = JSContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        let bundle = Bundle.main
        guard let path = bundle.path(forResource: "utf8", ofType: "js") else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let scriptSourceCode = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) else {
            return nil
        }
        context.evaluateScript(scriptSourceCode)
        let value = context.evaluateScript("utf8.decode(\"" + self + "\")")
        return value?.toString()
    }
}
```

However, this extension returns **undefined** sometimes, so I prefer the solution that @HangarRash added.